# How can I use classes to shorten this code?

Tags: python, class, fixed, ellipse

I have spent hours  trying to make a class in which a planets greatest and least distance from the sun is input (M and m) and the class will then print out the ellipse on a grid with the correct ellipse.

so far I have this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
#Set axes aspect to equal as orbits are almost circular.
ax = plt.figure(0).add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

#Setting the title, axis labels, axis values and introducing a grid underlay
#Variable used so title can indicate user inputed date
plt.title('Inner Planetary Orbits at[user input date]')
plt.ylabel('x10^6 km')
plt.xlabel('x10^6 km')
ax.set_xlim(-300, 300)
ax.set_ylim(-300, 300)
plt.grid()

#Creating the sun circle at the origin (not to scale), 
#intended to remain at a constant position and size so no variables are needed
ax.scatter(0,0,s=200,color='y')
plt.annotate('Sun', xy=(0,-30))

#Generate test ellipses 'Mercury' and 'Earth'


class PlanetOrbit:
    def __init__(self, name, M, m):
        self.name=name
        self.M=M
        self.m=m
        self.width=0
        self.height=0

    def OrbitLength(self):
        a=(self.M+self.m)/2
        c=a-self.m
        e=c/a
        b=((a**2)*(1-(e**2)))**0.5

        return b, a


    def WidthHeight(self, x, y):
        Width=2*x
        Height=2*y
        return Width, Height


x, y=PlanetOrbit('test',100,25).OrbitLength()
MercuryWidth, MercuryHeight=PlanetOrbit('test',100,25).WidthHeight(x, y)

x, y=PlanetOrbit('test',100,140).OrbitLength()
VenusWidth, VenusHeight=PlanetOrbit('test',100,40).WidthHeight(x, y)


Mercury = [Ellipse(xy=(0,0),width=MercuryWidth, height=MercuryHeight,angle=0, linewidth=1, fill=False)]

for e in Mercury:
    ax.add_artist(e)

Venus =  [Ellipse(xy=(0,0),width=VenusWidth, height=VenusHeight,angle=0, linewidth=1, fill=False)]

for e in Venus:
    ax.add_artist(e)




plt.show()
```

which works but the aim of this project is to reduce the amount of repetition with functions etc.

I dont understand classes well enough to improve this any further. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: This seems more suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since there is no programming error/problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but in this application, it seems as if you're just trying print out the eclipse of the grid. As this is just a simple task, you're better suited just a few methods. If you look at your `WidthHeight` method, you never use any of the variables in the class, just your arguments, so this should be outside the class, or at least static. Something like

```
def orbitLength(M, m):
    a=(M+m)/2
    c=a-m
    e=c/a
    b=((a**2)*(1-(e**2)))**0.5

    return b, a


def PlanetOrbit(name, M, m):
    w, h = orbitLength(M, m)
    e = Ellipse(xy=(0,0), width=w, height=h, angle=0, linewidth=1, fill=False)
    ax.add_artist(e)
```

Then you can simply call this like `PlanetOrbit('test',100,140)` which would do the same thing as your current code. It is good to learn how to use classes, but sometimes you also need to know when NOT to use them.